# Spotify: getting recent tracks (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

I've been searching for a way to display a list of the recent songs that have been played on my Spotify account, but without luck. My account is not linked to Facebook, so I can't get the history from facebook music.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You could sign up for last.fm, they track recents songs in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Vigrant above mentioned, there is no way to do this without some third party service. You can setup last.fm "scrobbling" so that you can view your track listening history.